# Access wordpress functions inside a plugin class

Tags: plugins

How to access wordpress functions inside a new main plugin class.?

`new_plugin_class` is the classname of plugin.

I want to get access all wordpress functions inside `new_plugin_class`.

like doing `require_once("..../.../.../wp_load.php");` for php pages.

is there any way to do it ??

Comment: wp in-built functions have global scope, so you can access them within your `new_plugin_class` class.

Answer (score 3):

In WordPress, most of the functions won't get loaded until certain points in the event stack. In the Event Driven Architecture [EDA] of WordPress, you have to put your classes into actions or filters.

```
class MyGreatClass{

    public function __construct(){
        //I can use WP functions here
    }

    public function myGreatMethod(){
        echo "I don't do much, but the WP functions are available to me!";
    }
}

//This line instantiates MyGreatClass and calls myGreatMethod during the "init" event.
add_action('init', array(new MyGreatClass, myGreatFunction'));
```

Comment: yesss......thats workng well...thanku soo muchh.... @John Dee

Comment: No problem. Click the up arrow to accept so others know this has an answer.